# How can I configure my GitHub account to refuse commits from unknown author

Tags: git, github

I have an account on GitHub with a custom pseudo / email address that I made up specifically for GitHub. However, on my PC, my default git identity (as in `~/.gitconfig`) uses a different pseudo and email address.

Whenever I clone a GitHub repository, I must manually update the repo identity with

```bash
git config user.name "..."
git config user.email "...@users.noreply.github.com"
```

If I don't so, commits I'll create on my PC then push to GitHub will appear as done by an unknown author.

Of course, I frequently forget to do these steps. I learned the hard way how to fix the mess of using a bad identity, but it remains some leftovers like pull requests, etc, that still refer to the commits with unknown author.

I'd like to know how I can configure my GitHub account, or better some repositories in that account, such that commits from unknown author (or even not from my GitHub account) are refused?

### Update

- Thanks for the tips, but checking the feature **Restrict editing to collaborators only** does not work. Actually it is enabled by default, and my collaborator list is empty. Still I can push with an unknown email address.
- **Blocking user** does not work either because it can only block known users. Maybe I could create a fake GitHub user with my other email address just for the sake of blocking it, but that seems a bit far fetched.
- Regarding `git config --global`, that's in fact what I did already. However I have a conflict between my GitHub identity and my other identities I use in other (non-GitHub) projects. So this would not solve my problem but move it elsewhere.

Comment: I think you can go the your target repo > settings > Options, then enable the option "Restrict editing to collaborators only".

Comment: You can set github's block users settings.

Comment: Why don't run `git config` with the option `--global`, this will edit `~/.gitconfig` so you don't have to do it every time you clone/create new repository into your local PC

Comment: One way to manage multiple identities in `git config` is to set it at the global level and use `includeIf` directive to override it at the level of individual directory trees

Comment: Did you work it out?

Comment: @zaitsman For a long time, I lived with a script that was overriding git. But avmohan suggestion's also work well. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @avmohan, it turns out there is indeed a nice feature in Git called **conditional include** that can be used to selectively apply configuration settings depending on the git dir location.

So a solution looks like this:

- Assume your default profile is `foo` / `foo@acme.org`, and your GitHub profile is `foo_hub`  / `foo_hub@users.noreply.github.com`.
- Assume you ALWAYS create your GitHub clones / repos in folder `~/github`.

You update your home git config file (`~/.gitconfig`) as follows:

```
[user]
  name = Foo
  email = foo@acme.org
[includeIf "gitdir:~/github/"]
  path = ~/github/.gitconfig
```

And you create the custom config file for github (`~/github/.gitconfig`) as follows:

```
[user]
  name = Foo_Hub
  email = foo_hub@users.noreply.github.com
```

From now on, creating / cloning a repository in that sub-folder will use that custom identity:

```bash
cd ~/github
mkdir foobar
cd foobar
git init
git config -l
# user.name=Foo
# user.email=foo@acme.org
# user.name=Foo_Hub
# user.email=foo_hub@users.noreply.github.com
```